# Al HaEitz on a Shehakol?

Tags: blessing, food, fruits, birkat-meeyn-shalosh, shehakol-beracha

Should you make al haeitz after a food containing a kezayis of the 7 species if it was not recognizable as such (=got a bracha rishona of shehakol) and/or there was no briyah (complete fruit)?

What if you made a shehakol because the 7 species was tofel, but you ate a kezayis?

Comment: I was once told by a Rav that if you make shehakol then you don't make a bracha achronah other than borei nefashos. I subsequently saw the MB in a couple places that if you make a shehakol missufik you should either (1) not eat a kazayis to avoid the after bracha or (2) eat something else to make borei nefashos and meein shalosh. Sorry don't have exact sources so only a comment.

Comment: @robev Amazing info. I was also taught that all shehakol is followed by borei nefashos. (I wanted to ask, at that time, about the borderline situations, but couldn't remember what they were.)

Comment: Does the situation in my question count as "shehakol missufik"? @robev

Comment: @robev And could you eat a kezayis of the food as long as it doesn't contain a kezayis of Seven Species content?

Comment: Whether there's any safek depends on if it's recognizable, so in your [first] case  it would be a definite shehakol. However, I believe robev is correct that the bracha achrona is b.n. I looked around a little and couldn't find any explicit source.

Comment: @Jay Don't you mean that in my first case, it would be a safek? Thanks

Comment: no, because your first case was "it was not recognizable as such" - if it's not recognizable the bracha is definitely shehakol, no safek. A safek would be, for instance, if it was mashed up but still recognizable.

Comment: I don't follow what the curiosity is. Can you check if the bracha on date spread (this is commonly available in supermarkets these days) is *ha'etz* and not *shehakol*? The dates are not recognizable. (The FRUIT dates, not the calendar ones :-)

Comment: @DanF Hmm. From here http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wpoxwK45D5gJ:ohraharon.weebly.com/uploads/5/5/1/9/55196825/changes_of_form_202.doc+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us : "he Shulchan Aruch 202:7 cites the Rambam that a date spread i.e. a date crushed and mixed into a paste retains its Bracha of Ha’ez"

Comment: @DanF If you read further in my link, basically everything and its opposite is said. I no longer have any idea what the halacha is for anything. At one point it even brings a shehakol for bread

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64311/discussion-between-danf-and-sah).